# Styled.Image show me error when I add ‘resize-mode‘

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

when I add 'resize-mode' in styled.Image under ReactNative and typescript, then vscode show me 'Unknown property: 'resize-mode'ts-styled-plugin(9999)'.

```
const TopImage = styled.Image`
resize-mode:'stretch';
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
`
```

Answer (score 0):

use object-fit instead of resize-mode

Comment: Thanks, because of styled-components have no this prop, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in tsconfig file

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "plugins": [
          {
            "name": "ts-styled-plugin",
            "lint": {
              "validProperties": [
                "resize-mode"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

or You can change ur code like

```
  <Image
        .....
        source={{..........}}
        resizeMode="stretch"
      />

const TopImage = styled.Image` 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
`
```